# How can I get files and links to open correctly in emacs?

Tags: spacemacs, environment

This used to work, but since a recent update, it hasn't. I'm using spacemacs, with [this configuration](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/dotfiles/blob/gnome3/dotfiles/spacemacs). Links and files don't open as usual. If I open `ansi-term`, and type `xdg-open test.txt`, then I see:

`xdg-open: line 617: kde-open5: command not found`.

Which makes sense, since I use GNOME, and not KDE. In a normal terminal (gnome-terminal), I don't have any `$KDE_x` variables, but in the emacs terminal, for some reason I have all kinds of variables set, like `$KDE_FULL_SESSION=true`. I thought this might be an issue with NixOS's packaging of emacs, but looking [where the package is defined](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/92a047a6c4d46a222e9c323ea85882d0a7a13af8/pkgs/applications/editors/emacs/default.nix) (I think), I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Is `kde-open5` in your `$PATH`? This doesn't really seem like an Emacs question, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't have `kde-open5` installed, because I don't use KDE. But somehow Emacs thinks I do.

Comment: Please add that info to the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. You might also want to `M-x debug-on-entry` for `xdg-open`, to see what calls that function and why that function tries to invoke command `kde-open5`.

Comment: @Drew, that information is already in the question itself. The mystery is not why `xdg-open` invokes `kde-open`, that's obvious. It apparently thinks I'm running KDE, because those KDE environment variables are set. But I'm not running KDE, and emacs terminals are the only places where those environment variables are set. The issue is that Emacs has somehow convinced itself that I'm running KDE, and thus tries to open commands like that which don't exist.

Comment: `debug-on-entry` for `xdg-open` will tell you what function called it, what called that function, etc. Saying only that "Emacs" thinks you're using KDE isn't enough, is it? You want to know *why* - what part of Emacs thinks that.

Comment: Can you check out your `~/.spacemacs.env` file? Possibly try to remove it and regenerate it.  There's been some changes in how it works recently and maybe your system got caught in the shuffle. There's a SO article here with a very similar issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095068/xdg-current-desktop-shows-kde-even-though-im-running-gnome-in-some-apps

Comment: @shoshin, thanks! That's the one. If you rewrite this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your `~/.spacemacs.env` file.  The newest version of Spacemacs has a function in the `.spacemacs` initialization file to load environment variables.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-env ()
  "Environment variables setup.
This function defines the environment variables for your Emacs session. By
default it calls `spacemacs/load-spacemacs-env' which loads the environment
variables declared in `~/.spacemacs.env' or `~/.spacemacs.d/.spacemacs.env'.
See the header of this file for more information."
  (spacemacs/load-spacemacs-env))
```

There's been some changes in how it works recently and maybe the environment variables that don't exist on your system got populated by mistake.  You can try to removing the `~/.spacemacs.env` file and regenerate with

`[M-x] spacemacs/force-init-spacemacs-env`

There's an [askUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095068/xdg-current-desktop-shows-kde-even-though-im-running-gnome-in-some-apps) here with a very similar issue that was resolved this way.